Observable property automatically reset with ObservableObject in MAUI
I'm new to MAUI and I'm triyng to use the MVVM model.
I have a viewModel BLEDeviceViewModel, a view MachineSelect and a model BLEDevice.
In MachineSelect.xaml.cs, I have the following code:
public partial class MachineSelect : ContentPage
{
    public MachineSelect(BLEDeviceViewModel viewModel)
    {
        BindingContext = viewModel;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

The instance of BLEDeviceViewModel is created in MauiProgram.cs as a singleton and injected when creating MachineSelect. In BLEDeviceViewModel.cs, I have this code:
    public partial class BLEDeviceViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        private BLEDevice _pairedDevice;

        public BLEDevice PairedDevice
        {
            get => _pairedDevice;
            set => SetProperty(ref _pairedDevice, value);
        }

        public BLEDeviceViewModel()
        {
            PairedDevice = new()
            {
                Name = Preferences.Get("PairedDeviceNAME", "Unknown"),
                UUID = Preferences.Get("PairedDeviceUUID", string.Empty)
            };
        }
    }
}

And in the BLEDevice model, the code is simple:
public class BLEDevice
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "";
    public string UUID { get; set; } = "";
}

The problem is that when I start the app, the _pairedDevice property gets initialized correctly but suddenly resets to a null value. I tried debugging and couldn’t find any reason for this. The issue seems to occur after the compiler finishes creating the instance of BLEDeviceViewModel, returns to the MachineSelect class, and when the InitializeComponent() method finishes, something calls the PairedDevice getter and then directly the setter with a value of null.
The code is very simple, so I’m struggling to find a solution.
I have tried using INotifyPropertyChanged instead of ObservableObject, but the issue remains. I also tried using [ObservableProperty] in my ViewModel and in my model, but nothing changed. The only way I found to run my application properly is to check the value before setting it:
public BLEDevice PairedDevice
{
    get => _pairedDevice;
    set
    {
        if (value != null)
            SetProperty(ref _pairedDevice, value);
    }
}

I have searched online in documentation and forums but couldn’t find anything similar. My code with the value checking works, but I don’t like it. I’m sure there’s a problem somewhere else

try calling InitializeComponent first

Yes, I tried this as well and I noticed that in this case the property reset occurs as soon as I finish the binding and not after the InitializeComponent(). So the problem seems to always happen when the MachineSelect constructor finishes.

How about using set =>_pairedDevice = value ? My code works fine.

@Emilio always use [ObservableProperty] AND always call InitializeComponents() first. If you are still having problem, look elsewhere. Something completely different is forcing this behavior.

Here's the modified part of my code,and it worked fine.

 get => _pairedDevice;
 set =>_pairedDevice = value;


